# How to optimize the process of importing a large graph with one hundred thousand vertexes and half a million edges into Orientdb by pyorient?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, pyorient

```
Orientdb : 2.1.3
Pyorient : 1.4.7
```

I need to import a graph with one hundred thousand vertexs and half a million edges into Orientdb by pyorient.

#### db.command one by one

Firstly, I just use db.command("create vertex V set a=1") to insert all the vertexes and edges one by one.

But it takes me about two hours.

So I want to find a way to optimize this process.

#### Massive Insert ?

Then I find that Orientdb supports **Massive Insert**, but unfortunately the author of pyorient in an issue [massive insertion: no transacations?](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/issues/96)  mentioned that

> in the bynary protocol ( and in pyorient of course ) there is not the massive insert intent.

#### SQL batch

Pyorient supports [sql batch](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient#execute-orientdb-sql-batch). Maybe this is an opportunity!

I just put all the insert commands together and run it by db.batch().

I take a graph with 5000 vertexes and 20000 edges for example

- sql batch

  ```
  vertexs : 25.1708816278 s
  edges : 254.248636227 s
  ```
- original

  ```
  constrct vertexs : 19.5094766904 s
  construct edges : 147.627924276 s
  ```

..it seems that sql batch costs much more time.

So I want to know whether there is a way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the one by one entry, you've already tried to see if you get better performance using Transactional Graph and commit every X items ?? Usually this is the correct way to insert a lot of data. Unfortunately using pyorient, as you also indicated you, the Massive Insert you can not use it and also Multi-process approaches are unable to exploit (the socket connection is only one and all your concurrent objects will be serialized ( as for a pipeline ) because a connection pool is not implemented in the driver. So you can loose the performance advantages of the multiprocessing).